# with windows universal app, is it possible to install an application programmatically

Tags: installation, win-universal-app, windows-10

i'm developing a windows universal app for win10 IOT.  I'm wanting to run a headless app that will download and install a new version of the application.  It would do something like this:
1) download app from blob storage
2) install app into the device
3) set app as startup
4) reboot the device

Is this possible?

Comment: how would that work with a headless device?  you login to App Store and tell it to push an update to the device?  you connect remotely to the device and somehow tell it to install something?  How is this latter situation any different than telling my service to download and install something.

Comment: My apologies. I have deleted my original response because it was not based on current data. AFAIK the official means for installing appx packages on Windows IOT has not yet been announced or confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this programmatically: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2012/11/05/how-do-i-deploy-a-windows-8-app-to-another-device-for-testing.aspx

Simply unzip the downloaded app package and run the power shell script.

But make sure you allow to install apps without the market: http://www.maketecheasier.com/install-windows-8-apps-without-storewindows-8/